# Having trouble moving class to seperate .cpp and .h file.

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++

I created a basic consol program that creates a box of the users desired height and width. I wanted to learn how classes worked so I just used one file. Now i'm trying to properly put the class into a .h and .cpp file. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and how I should fix it?

**Original Code with just a main.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BoxClass {
    //prv variables
    unsigned short int width;
    int height, i;
    float space_Value;
    float height_Count = 1;
    bool error = false;

    //prv functions
    void Print_Rectangle(int x, int y) {

        //calc
        space_Value = (3 * x) - 4;

        //draw top of box
        for (width = 1; width < x; width += 1) {
            cout << "...";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        //draw sides
        for (height = 1; height < y; height += 1) {
            cout << ":";
            height_Count++;
            for (width = 1; width < space_Value; width += 1) {
                cout << " ";
            }

            cout << ":\n";
        }

        //draw bottom
        cout << ":";

        for (width = 1; width < space_Value; width += 1) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << ":\n";
    }

public:
    //function shows area of individual spaces
    float Rectangle_Area() {
        if (error == false) {
            return (height_Count - .5)*(space_Value - 1);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //function shows area of individual spaces

    // constructor
    BoxClass(int x, int y, int amount) {

        if (x <= 41) {
            for (i = 1; i <= amount; i += 1) {
                Print_Rectangle(x, y);
            }
        }
        else {
            error = true;
            cout << "Error - width must be below 42!\n";
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    //variable declaration/definition
    int width_Var;
    int height_Var;
    int number_of_Boxes;

    //object declaration/Body
    cout << "Enter width of rectangle/box\nWidth = ";
    cin >> width_Var;
    cout << "Enter height of rectangle/box\nHeight = ";
    cin >> height_Var;
    cout << "How many rectangles/boxes do you want?\n";
    cin >> number_of_Boxes;

    BoxClass box1(width_Var, height_Var, number_of_Boxes);

    cout <<"Box Area = "<<box1.Rectangle_Area() << endl;

//exit
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**New Code with main.cpp, BoxClass.h, Boxclass.cpp:**

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "BoxClass.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    //variable declaration/definition
    int width_Var;
    int height_Var;
    int number_of_Boxes;

    //object declaration/Body
    cout << "Enter width of rectangle/box\nWidth = ";
    cin >> width_Var;
    cout << "Enter height of rectangle/box\nHeight = ";
    cin >> height_Var;
    cout << "How many rectangles/boxes do you want?\n";
    cin >> number_of_Boxes;

    BoxClass box1(width_Var, height_Var, number_of_Boxes);

    cout <<"Box Area = "<<box1.Rectangle_Area() << endl;

//exit
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**BoxClass.h:**

```
#ifndef BOXCLASS_H
#define BOXCLASS_H

class BoxClass {
    //prv variables
    unsigned short int width;
    int height, i;
    float space_Value;
    float height_Count = 1;
    bool error = false;

    //prv functions
    void Print_Rectangle(int x, int y);

public:
    //function shows area of individual spaces
    float Rectangle_Area();
    //function shows area of individual spaces

    // constructor
    BoxClass(int x, int y, int amount);
};

#endif
```

**BoxClass.cpp:**

```
#include "BoxClass.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    BoxClass::Print_Rectangle(int x, int y) {

        //calc
        space_Value = (3 * x) - 4;

        //draw top of box
        for (width = 1; width < x; width += 1) {
            cout << "...";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        //draw sides
        for (height = 1; height < y; height += 1) {
            cout << ":";
            height_Count++;
            for (width = 1; width < space_Value; width += 1) {
                cout << " ";
            }

            cout << ":\n";
        }

        //draw bottom
        cout << ":";

        for (width = 1; width < space_Value; width += 1) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << ":\n";
    }


    //function shows area of individual spaces
    BoxClass::Rectangle_Area() {
        if (error == false) {
            return (height_Count - .5)*(space_Value - 1);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // constructor
    BoxClass::BoxClass(int x, int y, int amount) {

        if (x <= 41) {
            for (i = 1; i <= amount; i += 1) {
                Print_Rectangle(x, y);
            }
        }
        else {
            error = true;
            cout << "Error - width must be below 42!\n";
        }
    };
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of the code that makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: Are you getting any compiler error with separate .cpp and .h files? Can you be more specific in what is the error is?

Comment: Get rid of `#include “stdafx.h”`. Or put it first.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you so much, you solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about type specifier so you should change this in your BoxClass.cpp:

```
BoxClass::Print_Rectangle(int x, int y)
...
BoxClass::Rectangle_Area()
```

to this:

```
void BoxClass::Print_Rectangle(int x, int y)
...
float BoxClass::Rectangle_Area()
```

Also a bit aside of topic, thing that I can suggest you for future is to use `#pragma once` instead include guards.

Comment: Kalinowski I have a ton of errors about all the variables. heres just one. 1>c:\users\cade\source\repos\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\boxclass.cpp(22): error C2065: 'width': undeclared identifier

Comment: @Zack Oliver this results from the lack of information, there was no talk of incorrect linking, also you don't give info if your "stdafx.h" even exist, so I assumed that it exist somewhere. No wonder that removing it worked. Pls, if you resolve your problem then select the best answer that help you as solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor, which is where you'll set the values of height_Count and error. You should probably also define a destructor, even though at this point there is probably nothing to do there. It's just a good idea. According to Scott Meyers in Effective C++, you should also define a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator.

This is in addition to the type-specifier suggestion already posted.